# List with tuples inside to string in Python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, scripting

I'm new to Python, and I'm using Python3. I need to convert lists with tuples inside(

```
randstr = list("QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM")
randint = list("1234567890")

shuffle(randint)
shuffle(randstr)

print(zip(randint[:6], randstr[:6]))
```

It works, and I get lists with tuples inside like:

```
[('6', 'Q'), ('0', 'P'), ('3', 'H'), ('5', 'B'), ('2', 'U'), ('4', 'E')]
[('9', 'E'), ('1', 'Q'), ('7', 'D'), ('4', 'A'), ('3', 'T'), ('0', 'X')]
[('4', 'P'), ('9', 'B'), ('2', 'S'), ('1', 'A'), ('3', 'Y'), ('7', 'F')]
```

However, I want to output strings, not lists (and I need strings without the tuples), like

```
"6Q 0P 3H 5B 2U 4E"
```

Just if you want to know, I'm trying to make a script that randomly changes my mac adress. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use format and join:

```
print(' '.join('%s%s' % i for i in zip(randint[:6], randstr[:6])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join the string pairs and construct the result string:

```
>>> " ".join(["".join(item) for item in zip(randint[:6], randstr[:6])])
'3D 4V 6L 8W 0S 1I'
```